# Preview Base64 ppt, pptx files in browser - Angular 6, Bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am creating web application using Angular 6. Base 64 data for ppt/pptx file is already available in DB. Now when user clicks on preview button, I will call ajax to get base64 data of ppt file and I should open the ppt file in new tab.

I tried Google Docs, ngx-docs-viewer but all these all are not supporting Base64 input.

I tried to directly append the base64 data src into iframe. But still no luck.

Please suggest is there any plugin available to preview base64 ppt/pptx.

Comment: Why not decode Base64 on the server side? Less data to transmit too.

Comment: Hi Joop, can you please explain your idea? How decoding in server will help me to preview the file?

Comment: No viewer will be able to do something with Base64, which more or less scrambles the original binary data. Powerpoint (browser plugin?) must have the valid original binary data. So one streams the decoded binary data with `Content-Type:` ppt=`application/mspowerpoint`, pptx=`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation`.

Comment: @sasi did you manage to get solution of it?

Comment: @A_01- Yes, i appended the base 64 data into object tag. Basically you will be able to see the file, if your browser supports or has the additional extension installed in your browser. So I have condition to check whether the browser can load the file, if not I display an error message asking the user to install the required plugin.